# why these tags showed in the result when search a user

Tags: bug, tags, search

When I search someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users), there are some tags showed in the result along with the avatar of the user. I used to think they are the top tags of the user until I search myself. The tags showed up are not my top tags, and I didn't get any score with them.

My question is :
**Is this the feature or there is something wrong ?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the tags in which you earned the most reputation in the time period selected (I'm guessing "month" from looking at your [activity page at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6171361/sel-fish?tab=answers&sort=newest)). You earned 95 points from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37700039/2825369), and sure enough, the question has those tags.

Comment: yes, i think you're right, the reputation and the tags showed are related to a time period, not the overall.